# Bots taking over my site

Tags: 7

I just noticed that bots have been taking over my Drupal website for quite a few weeks. There are over 600 pages of content. I only noticed now because the website is on hold (still available online) at the moment. I just got a message from the hosting company that the maximum disk space has been reached, which came as a total surprise.

I've tried changing password but it's still uploading. I deleted the *Basic page* content type because all the content was created with that content type, but now they are using a different content type, and the content is still there even though I thought it would remove all the content when I removed basic page.

How can I stop them from creating content?

Comment: Did the bots create accounts? or somehow they are accessing your admin account? can anonymous users create content or authenticated users or only admins?

Comment: Only admins and they're creating content in my name

Comment: `Only admins and they're creating content in my name` then you got hacked. [Your Drupal site got hacked. Now what?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2365547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the People config page you can set up who can register accounts. Put that option on `Administrators only`. 
After that identify the bots users and delete them (make sure to delete them, not just disable).
Then, identify content created by bots and delete it.
Also, don't forget to check who can create content on the website (permissions page).

Comment: Just to add: When you delete user accounts, you're presented with an option to delete their content or keep it.

Comment: Good point, I think he is referring to Drupal 7. In Drupal 8 there is no option for deleting the content when deleting the user, just unpublish it or make it belong to Anonymous user.